# Steps to compile darwin for arm on ubuntu gcc

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling, darwin

Has anyone got the steps to compile darwin libraries on gcc for arm on ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [site](http://ostatic.com/darwin-arm) that provides patches for and arm darwin kernel.

> Darwin on ARM develops and provides patches for the Apple Darwin-xnu kernel sources so that it can be cross-compiled to run on an ARM processor.

This ubuntu [forum entry](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=360877) shows how to install the arm-linux-gcc cross compiler.

Put the two together and you should get what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross

step by step install it ref to https://enigma-dev.org/docs/wiki/index.php?title=CrossCompileLinuxOSX